# My current insurance doesn't fulfill the requirements for a Schengen visa. Can I buy extra insurance in addition to my existing one?

Tags: schengen, insurance, vietnamese-citizens, us-residents

I am living in the US (in fact, even considered resident for tax purposes, I had been here for a long time; citizenship is Vietnam) and planning to travel to the Schengen region in July-August. I need a letter from health insurance stating that I am fully covered at least €30,000 in the region for the full duration. My problem is two-fold:
- The insurance company refused to put the amount of money on the letter.
- My insurance expired at the end of July, and I can renew it only starting from the end of June, but I need to apply for visa now.

I can't really buy another insurance (I think it is even illegal to have two insurances) besides that would be too expensive.

Is there a good way to deal with this situation (I am sure people have experienced this before, since student insurance tend to expire in the summer)?

What can I do?

My school insurance people said it happened very frequently, but they can't do anything about that since it is the company's rules, so I had to ask the Internet.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Travel! I think you made a typo in the second sentence, "I am the US". I am unsure whether you mean you're a US citizen or just in the US, so I didn't make an edit. If you're not a US citizen, can you tell us your citizenship?

Comment: I doubt if the OP is a USA citizen, as then s/he would not need a visa, and I have NEVER had a border guard ask for details about my insurance. (I do have an insurance card, but it doesn't discuss limits.) But I believe this is a requirement to apply for a Schengen visa.

Comment: It shouldn't be illegal to have more than one health insurance policy, though the issue of which one "is primary" (is responsible for paying first) if you need to use it can be complicated. The expiration issue is a problem though, and may require that you buy a new policy for your trip. I'd contact the office at your school that deals with student health insurance since this can't be the first time someone has had this problem. If you can't work this out another way, buying travel insurance for your trip will cover you at a moderate cost.

Comment: One workaround would be to buy travel insurance. I have a life insurance that do not have travel insurance, so I usually buy ad-hoc travel insurance for the duration I'll be abroad, and they usually come inexpensive.

Answer (score 5):

Having two (or even more insurances) is certainly not illegal: the insurance companies are more than happy to take as much of your money as possible. There might be potential issues if you've arranged the insurances as part of a scam, but that's obviously not the scenario.

So the proper answer is to buy a Schengen travel insurance and use that to get a Schengen visa.